# How to extract the nth row of a sql statement?

Tags: sql

I am trying to extract the nth row of an SQL statement (not the nth row of a table).
Is there an easy way to run a query and read values from specific rows.

I have tried something similar to this but it does not work since rownum tells me what nth record it is in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RewardID ASC) AS rownumber,
        RewardID,
        Name,
        Description,
        Image,
        RewardType,
        price
    FROM
        Reward
) AS num 
WHERE
    RewardType = 'Electronics' and rownum = 2
```

Comment: can you provide an example of what you are trying to do? what do you have and what do you want?  actual data would be helpful

Comment: So I have data I want to cycle through but I don't know how to make the data reader go to the next line. Im trying to reader data from a select statement where the item category is electronics. after I read the first electronic I cant move to the next one.

Comment: @AaronB What you seem to want to do based on your comment isn't what you're asking for. If you're using a data reader that data reader would have the functions you want in it, you would want to return the whole dataset to the reader, in c# for instance it's done with SqlDataReader.Read()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Postgres Or SQLServer? Both have a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, but the syntax, especially around subqueries, may be slightly different. I'll assume Postgres.

You query looks good to me, except that the `rownum = 2` in your `WHERE` should presumably be `rownumber = 2`, since that's what you aliased the `ROW_NUMBER()` column as. You also presumably don't need the `RewardType` and `rownumber` columns in your result, since their values will always be `'Electronics'` and `2` respectively. Corrected and formatted for readability, this looks ok to me:

```
SELECT RewardID, Name, Description, Image, RewardType, price
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RewardID ASC) AS rownumber,
        RewardID,
        Name,
        Description,
        Image,
        RewardType,
        price
    FROM Reward) AS num
WHERE RewardType = 'Electronics' and rownumber = 2
```

The only questionable part of that is the `WHERE RewardType = 'Electronics'`. Should that actually be in the subquery rather than the outer query? The difference is that if it is in the subquery, the row counting will include only reward type 'Electronics', whereas in the outer query, all reward types will be counted. To only count the reward type 'Electronics', modify it as so:

```
SELECT RewardID, Name, Description, Image, RewardType, price
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RewardID ASC) AS rownumber,
        RewardID,
        Name,
        Description,
        Image,
        RewardType,
        price
    FROM Reward
    WHERE RewardType = 'Electronics') AS num
WHERE rownumber = 2
```

Edit: Since the comment you just made clarifies what you're really trying to do, I'll add that you should NOT be making an individual query for each row of the data that you want. Whatever interface you are using to your database will have a way of iterating over a query result that uses multiple rows, and if that's what you really need, you should find out how to do that.

Comment: You are a god sent thank you. My issue was that where statement

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `OFFSET/FETCH`:

```
SELECT
    RewardID,
    Name,
    Description,
    Image,
    RewardType,
    price
FROM Reward
WHERE RewardType = 'Electronics'
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Tell it to `OFFSET`(skip) row 1 then `FETCH`(select) 1 row after that, which would be row 2. This removes the need for a sub select.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the order by, try using null in the order by.`SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select null)) AS rownumber,
        RewardID,
        Name,
        Description,
        Image,
        RewardType,
        price
    FROM
        Reward
) AS num 
WHERE
    RewardType = 'Electronics' and rownum = 2`